# Handling promise in nested loops

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise

I am new to Promise. I have a scenario where a list of object inside another list of objects should be updated based on a response from external api.

I tried to simulate a sample scenario as shown below.
In the below code i have list of flights where the destlist array inside the Flights array has to be updated by adding new fields which will be taken form users array based on userId. Below is the codepen url.

```js
const flights = [
  {
    data: {
      legid: 1,
      name: "A380",
      destlist: [
        {
          city: "city1",
          userId: 1
        },
        {
          city: "city2",
          userId: 2
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      legid: 2,
      name: "A380",
      destlist: [
        {
          city: "city1",
          userId: 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];

const users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Andrew",
    schoolId: 101
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Jessica",
    schoolId: 999
  }
];

const getUser = id => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const user = users.find(user => user.id === id);
    if (user) {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(user), 1000);
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => reject(`Unable to find user with id of ${id}.`), 1000);
    }
  });
};

prettyJSON(
  Promise.all(
    flights.map(function(flt) {
      return Promise.all(
        flt.data.destlist.map(function(item) {
          getUser(item.userId)
            .then(us => (item.name = us.name))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
          return flt;
        })
      );
    })
  ).then(function(data) {
    prettyJSON(data);
  })
);

function prettyJSON(obj) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
}
```

> https://codepen.io/prabuj201987/pen/mGvRjL?editors=1012
>
> Current output

```
    [
      [
        {
          'data': {
            'legid': 1,
            'name': 'A380',
            'destlist': [
              {
                'city': 'city1',
                'userId': 1
              },
              {
                'city': 'city2',
                'userId': 2
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          'data': {
            'legid': 1,
            'name': 'A380',
            'destlist': [
              {
                'city': 'city1',
                'userId': 1
              },
              {
                'city': 'city2',
                'userId': 2
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          'data': {
            'legid': 2,
            'name': 'A380',
            'destlist': [
              {
                'city': 'city1',
                'userId': 2
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
```

> Expected output

```
  [
  [
    {
      "data": {
        "legid": 1,
        "name": "A380",
        "destlist": [
          {
            "city": "city1",
            "userId": 1,
            "name": "Andrew"
          },
          {
            "city": "city2",
            "userId": 2,
            "name": "Jessica"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "legid": 1,
        "name": "A380",
        "destlist": [
          {
            "city": "city1",
            "userId": 1,
            "name": "Andrew"
          },
          {
            "city": "city2",
            "userId": 2,
            "name": "Jessica"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "data": {
        "legid": 2,
        "name": "A380",
        "destlist": [
          {
            "city": "city1",
            "userId": 2,
            "name": "Jessica"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
]
```

Need advice on how to do this.

Comment: Please post your code here as a [mcve] instead of just links to codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could use async/await, it would be easier to imagine and implement a more readable solution like this

```
Promise.all(flights.map(async flight => {
  const destlist = flight.data.destlist

  const updatedDestList = await Promise.all(destlist.map(async dest => {
    const user = await getUser(dest.userId)

    dest.name = user.name

    return dest
  }))

  flight.destlist = updatedDestList

  return flight
}))
```

The full working example

```js
const flights = [
  {
    data: {
      legid: 1,
      name: "A380",
      destlist: [
        {
          city: "city1",
          userId: 1
        },
        {
          city: "city2",
          userId: 2
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    data: {
      legid: 2,
      name: "A380",
      destlist: [
        {
          city: "city1",
          userId: 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];

const users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Andrew",
    schoolId: 101
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Jessica",
    schoolId: 999
  }
];

const getUser = id => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const user = users.find(user => user.id === id);
    if (user) {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(user), 1000);
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => reject(`Unable to find user with id of ${id}.`), 1000);
    }
  });
};

Promise.all(flights.map(async flight => {
  const destlist = flight.data.destlist
    
  const updatedDestList = await Promise.all(destlist.map(async dest => {
    const user = await getUser(dest.userId)
      
    dest.name = user.name
      
    return dest
  }))
    
  flight.destlist = updatedDestList
    
  return flight
}))
.then(function(data) {
  prettyJSON(data);
})

function prettyJSON(obj) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since function `getUser` executes asynchronously, you should return data when it's fulfilled. Use `async/await`:

```
    return Promise.all(
      flt.data.destlist.map(async function (item) {
        await getUser(item.userId)
          .then(us => (item.name = us.name))
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
        return flt;
      }),
    );
```

Or if you're unfamiliar with `async/await`, you can return the `getUser` call directly:

```
Promise.all(
  flights.map(function (flt) {
    return Promise.all(
      flt.data.destlist.map(function (item) {
        return getUser(item.userId)
          .then(us => {
            item.name = us.name;
            return flt;
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
      }),
    );
  }),
).then(function (data) {
  prettyJSON(data);
});
```

This way `flt.data.destlist.map` returns an array of `Promise`, so `Promise.all` will wait.

Also the outer `prettyJSON` is not a need, and it's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't return Promise but return value of `flt` `Promise.all` will not wait until data is loaded.

```
getUser(item.userId)
        .then(us => (item.name = us.name))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
return flt;
```

Make it as `return getUser(...`.